# Auto-select proper field for barcode reader with javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a web-based application for our warehouse folks.  What I'd like to do is direct their barcode scanner input to a particular field on the form....ie, enter scanned data into the tracking number field regardless of where the current focus is.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Isaac:  The scanner is a Symbol brand scanner that plugs directly into the USB port.  Right now, it acts as keyboard input.  Currently, when a barcode is scanned, the input is entered into whatever field currently has focus.

Comment: As for what I've tried, that would be nothing.  I'd like to find out if it's possible....hence, the question on a knowledge-based site with 800k+ users.

Comment: Obviously not that easy. For example, essential information like whether the barcode reader can only output those characters it reads or whether it can precede some magic/identifying characters before starting the actual output or information what kind of barcode it reads.
Does it have an unambiguously identifiable format -- is it e.g. identifiable in a character sequence together with different user input. Dependent on that, I would bind event handlers for key strokes to the document and then decide whether typing speed is something to be considered or not.